# Power Series without computation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^n}{n!}x^n$$

Now obviously I can use the ratio test to prove that the Radius of convergence is $\frac{1}{e}$ but what the question asks is that using little computation prove why the Radius of convergence of this power series satisfies $R\leq1$. I know the question is ambiguous but is there any concept I can use to prove this? This question was on a past quiz and unfortunately, there is no solution that I can look at...

Comment: at $x=1$ the series diverges thus the radius of convergence is $\le 1$

Comment: If you can prove the radius of convergence is $R = \frac{1}{e}$, then it sounds like you just want a proof that $\frac{1}{e} \le 1$?

Comment: No, the instructor says that with little computation meaning without using any tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_n = \frac{n^n}{n!}$. For the radius of convergence $R$ we have
$$ \frac{1}{R} = \limsup_n \sqrt[n]{a_n}. $$

Since clearly $a_n \geq 1$, also $\sqrt[n]{a_n} \geq 1$, so $\frac{1}{R} \geq 1 \implies R \leq 1$.

Comment: I don't understand the concept of $\limsup$ as it was never taught to me is there another way?

Comment: Then the comment by @Aditya should be the clearest.

Comment: @AhsonYousef A simple comparison would work. Hugo notes that each term in the series (when $x = 1$) is bounded below by $1$. This means the terms do not converge to $0$, and hence the series must diverge when $x = 1$.

Comment: Oh I get it! So that is what $$\limsup$$ means that it oscillates(bounded) between a certain pair of numbers or under a number. Thanks, guys much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think your instructor hoped you would notice that $n^n \ge n!$ (actually, greater when $n>1$).

At $x = 1$  the terms in this infinite sum are all at least  $1$   so the series can't converge there.

Comment: Finer approximations could use $\left(\frac n3\right)^n\le n!\le \left(\frac n2\right)^n$ and then the series $\sum |x|^{2n}\le S(|x|)\le \sum |x|^{3n}$ and $\frac 13\le R\le \frac 12$, but I admit none of them are as straightforward as $n!\le n^n$.